# How to download google drive folder from others public drive directly into colab without downloading into pc?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I was trying to learn running the human pose estimation HRNet model in google colab. Problem is that we have really slow internet here. And my google drive also does not have enough storage. So, I would like to directly get the google drive folder that the authors stated in their git repo into my google colab directory which has enough space. How can I do that? Also, how can I get the datasets from websites directly into Google Colab using the link? Is it possible?

I couldn't do it using wget because of the following message:

```
!wget 'https://doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com/download/8ms8b89eqn0kfkoe2asvf6kn35pv2835/5bjm43l1uvq11mghfs876f196ug1g3rp/1599664500000/e97bd50e-8abd-4462-86b8-d28c67b5a33d/110209733636068532482/ADt3v-NmPxhenWuLgjH2m5c8emE66pjdExmgep47BAdKTrsso2Vu8Ke6GEY5W51wwPPMqKZJowXQCea0f7Y2ef0oWZN1GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiTDSVDAsZOS2VM8r39rCpZvMmSw7e1cM7M013RuxVt5ixo9ZaBeRpN5iSQnbbchwr-KXlnb5eOOsKsMRgODhgctBzGiuh-sX1wfd36HlckQEaQ1U3k8rlVTYPU2vHK0fYUHeZKpvANdEZ0Y0s_fHX-YlAz1rr7tk0BZYF2-qYB_MBtp8bhrdDnNPPgDeUrbPF0Ow2hEYnYhiLm9?authuser=0&nonce=t0vkqcsfq608e&user=110209733636068532482&hash=9ckphlkqrvig75uleqg3b931o1ft9r2p' // error message below:


The name is too long, 428 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is ADt3v-NmPxhenWuLgjH2m5c8emE66pjdExmgep47BAdKTrsso2Vu8Ke6GEY5W51wwPPMqKZJowXQCea0f7Y2ef0oWZN1GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiTDSVDAsZOS2VM8r39rCpZvMmSw7e1cM7M013RuxVt5ixo9ZaBeRpN5iSQnbbchwr-KXlnb5eOOsKsMRgODhgctBzGiuh-sX1wfd36HlckQEaQ1.
--2020-09-09 17:47:39--  https://doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com/download/8ms8b89eqn0kfkoe2asvf6kn35pv2835/5bjm43l1uvq11mghfs876f196ug1g3rp/1599664500000/e97bd50e-8abd-4462-86b8-d28c67b5a33d/110209733636068532482/ADt3v-NmPxhenWuLgjH2m5c8emE66pjdExmgep47BAdKTrsso2Vu8Ke6GEY5W51wwPPMqKZJowXQCea0f7Y2ef0oWZN1GV9Jm2u7rmsCe65wKzPTw5jtS38n2tVEGiTDSVDAsZOS2VM8r39rCpZvMmSw7e1cM7M013RuxVt5ixo9ZaBeRpN5iSQnbbchwr-KXlnb5eOOsKsMRgODhgctBzGiuh-sX1wfd36HlckQEaQ1U3k8rlVTYPU2vHK0fYUHeZKpvANdEZ0Y0s_fHX-YlAz1rr7tk0BZYF2-qYB_MBtp8bhrdDnNPPgDeUrbPF0Ow2hEYnYhiLm9?authuser=0&nonce=t0vkqcsfq608e&user=110209733636068532482&hash=9ckphlkqrvig75uleqg3b931o1ft9r2p
Resolving doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com (doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com)... 108.177.112.132, 2607:f8b0:4001:c12::84
Connecting to doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com (doc-8s-68-drive-data-export.googleusercontent.com)|108.177.112.132|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Server Error
2020-09-09 17:47:39 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error.
```

Comment: That link to the repository doesn't seem correct. Where did you copy it from?

Comment: When I tried to download with IDM, it showed an address. I used that address.

Answer (score 0):

The link that you have to the file is incorrect. It should be much shorter.
It should look something like:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/rAndomlEtt3r5andNumb3rs/view?usp=sharing

The file id is the rAndomlEtt3r5andNumb3rs part of the link

Assuming the authors have sharing enabled to 'Anyone with Link' and not restricted to certain users you can download the file (in this example named exampledata.csv)

you can download the file with:

```
!gdown --id rAndomlEtt3r5andNumb3rs

> Downloading...
> From: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=rAndomlEtt3r5andNumb3rs
> To: /content/exampledata.csv
> 0.00B [00:00, ?B/s]
```

It will save to the temporary folder /content/ in your Colab session. You can navigate to that with the folder icon on the left.
To access it, load the file in your work space at

```
/content/exampledata.csv
```

I'm not sure what the storage limit is there, but I've routinely downloaded 10GB of files to it. But remember EVERYTHING saved there is deleted at the end of your session.

If you don't have permission to download the file, you'll get:

```
Permission denied: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=8ms8b89eqn0kfkoe2asvf6kn35pv2835
Maybe you need to change permission over 'Anyone with the link'?
```

Comment: I was hoping if it is possible to get all the folders and files of that public drive without zipping it. Fetching it directly. Also, having limited storage and slow internet connection, I cannot fetch one of the zip files of the HRNet and extract it there. I tried uploading manually, but the session times out.